# Sklearn: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have built a model.

```
est1_pre = ColumnTransformer([('catONEHOT', OneHotEncoder(dtype='int',handle_unknown='ignore'),['Var1'])],remainder='drop')
est2_pre = ColumnTransformer([('BOW', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3),max_features=1000),['Var2'])],remainder='drop')


    m1= Pipeline([('FeaturePreprocessing', est1_pre),
                              ('clf',alternative)])
    m2= Pipeline([('FeaturePreprocessing', est2_pre),
                              ('clf',alternative)])
    model_combo = StackingClassifier(
         estimators=[('cate',m1),('text',m2)],
         final_estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10,
                                               random_state=42)
     )
```

I can successfully, fit and predict using `m1` and `m2`.
However, when I look at the combination `model_combo`
Any attempt in calling .fit/.predict results in `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:`

```
    model_fitted=model_combo.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

x_train contains `Var1` and `Var2`
How to fit `model_combo?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that sklearn text preprocessors (`TfidfVectorizer` in this case) operate on one-dimensional data, not two-dimensional as most other preprocessors. So the vectorizer treats its input as an iterable of its *columns*, so there's only one "document".  This can be fixed in the `ColumnTransformer` by specifying the column to operate on *not* in a list:

```py
est2_pre = ColumnTransformer([('BOW', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3),max_features=1000),'Var2')],remainder='drop')
```